# Generate barcode for an order in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.5, barcode

I tried to follow this [link](https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-barcode-and-add-it-in-magento-2-invoice-pdf/) for generating barcode for an order, but looks like 2.4.5 doesnt support Zend Barcode anymore.  Can anyone guide me on how to take an orderId and generate a barcode unique for that particular order.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Comment: Yes, I used something from gitlab
https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode/